# pandas write dataframe to parquet format with fastparquet and load it into azure blob storage

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-blob-storage

For a project i want to write a pandas dataframe with fast parquet and load it into azure blob storage. In order to do a `".append"` to this file.

```
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from io import BytesIO

# Create a Pandas DataFrame
data = {'Column1': [4,5,6], 'Column2': ["D","E","F"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(azure_connection_string)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob="https://code.blob.core.windows.net/odif")

blob_name = "test5.parquet"
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, blob_name)

print(blob_client)

parquet_file = BytesIO()

df.to_parquet(parquet_file, engine='fastparquet')

blob_client.upload_blob(
    data=parquet_file
)
```

but when i run this code i have this error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/francoislenne/insertion_etudiant_univ_lille/POC_pdf_odif.ipynb Cellule 27 line 2
     18 parquet_file = BytesIO()
     20 df.to_parquet(parquet_file, engine='fastparquet')
---> 22 blob_client.upload_blob(
     23     data=parquet_file
     24 )

File ~/insertion_etudiant_univ_lille/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py:78, in distributed_trace.<locals>.decorator.<locals>.wrapper_use_tracer(*args, **kwargs)
     76 span_impl_type = settings.tracing_implementation()
     77 if span_impl_type is None:
---> 78     return func(*args, **kwargs)
     80 # Merge span is parameter is set, but only if no explicit parent are passed
     81 if merge_span and not passed_in_parent:

File ~/insertion_etudiant_univ_lille/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/storage/blob/_blob_client.py:749, in BlobClient.upload_blob(self, data, blob_type, length, metadata, **kwargs)
    605 @distributed_trace
    606 def upload_blob(
    607         self, data: Union[bytes, str, Iterable[AnyStr], IO[AnyStr]],
   (...)
    611         **kwargs
    612     ) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    613     """Creates a new blob from a data source with automatic chunking.
    614 
...
---> 76     current_position = data.tell()
     77     data.seek(0, SEEK_END)
     78     length = data.tell() - current_position

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

i try with pyarrow library and this code working correctly.

How can i resolve this error ?

Thanks in advance,

i try with pyarrow library and this code working correctly :

```
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
from io import BytesIO

# Create a Pandas DataFrame
data = {'Column1': [4,5,6], 'Column2': ["D","E","F"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(azure_connection_string)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob="https://code.blob.core.windows.net/odif")

blob_name = "test5.parquet"
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, blob_name)

print(blob_client)

parquet_file = BytesIO()

df.to_parquet(parquet_file, engine='pyarrow')

blob_client.upload_blob(
    data=parquet_file
)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to write pandas dataframe with fast parquet and load it into
> Azure blob storage. In order to do a `".append"` to this file.

You can use the below code to upload a parquet file without downloading from the local file system.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Column1': [4, 5, 6], 'Column2': ["D", "E", "F"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

azure_connection_string = "xxxxxx"
container_name = "demo"

df.to_parquet(f'abfss://{container_name}/test10.parquet', engine='fastparquet',storage_options={'connection_string':azure_connection_string})
```

Here, `abfss` protocol is used to write to the Azure Blob Storage filesystem. The `engine` is set to `fastparquet` to use the fastparquet library for writing the Parquet file. The `storage_options` is used to pass the Azure Blob Storage connection string to the `fastparquet` library.

Now if you need to read the file from Azure blob storage you can use the below code.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
azure_connection_string = "xxxxx"
container_name = "demo"

print(pd.read_parquet(f'abfss://{container_name}/test10.parquet',storage_options={'connection_string':azure_connection_string}))
```

**Output:**

```
   Column1 Column2
0        4       D
1        5       E
2        6       F
```

[image]

Before running code you need install [**fsspec**](https://pypi.org/project/fsspec/) and [**adlfs**](https://pypi.org/project/adlfs/) Python package.

**Reference:**
[Tutorial: Use Pandas to read/write ADLS data | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool)